# Has a probability density function a weak derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, weak-derivatives

Assume I have a probability density function $\rho$ on $R$. (e.g $\rho \geq 0$ $\int \rho dx =1 $ $\rho \in L^1(R)$ ...). So $\rho$ is the density wrt the lebesgue measure.

Now I try to understand if $\rho$ itself has again a weak derivative.

Is this true in general?

If not: What are conditions on $\rho$ to have weak derivative?

Edit: Is absolute continuity of $\rho$ in this case equivalent to existence of a weak derivative?

(I know absolute cont ==> weak derivative.. Is the other direction also true? So is absolute continuity of $\rho$ necessary and sufficient?)

Comment: What is a weak derivative? I suggest you look up and understand the Radon-Nikodym theorem.
This explains how to take the derivative of one measure with respect to another measure and sufficient/necessary criterias for when such things exist.

Comment: Yes, except that here the OP wants to differentiate the Radon-Nykodym derivative itself (hence second order differentiation, so to speak)...

Comment: This is not about PDFs but about any integrable function.

Comment: So you mean there is not advantage in having a PDF?
But what is the answer for general $L^1$-functions?

Comment: Exactly I am looking for a second order derivative... I edited my first post to make this clear.

Answer (score 1):

Any function has a distributional derivative - I'm guessing you want the derivative to also be an $L^1$ function, i.e. $\rho \in W^{1,1}(\mathbb R)$? In this case you're almost right - $W^{1,1}(\mathbb R)$ is the space of absolutely continuous functions *that are also $L^1$ with $L^1$ derivatives*. If you restrict yourself to a bounded interval (or work with *locally* weakly differentiable functions) then the notions coincide.